# How can I enumerate the SQL server instances on the LAN in VBA?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

How can I enumerate the SQL server instances on the LAN in VBA?

This is for Microsoft Office 2019 on Windows 10, and the servers are various versions from 2008 to 2019.

I have an Excel workbook which uses ADODB 2.8 in VBA to run queries on one SQL instance. I would like to expand the code to run the queries for any instance on our LAN. To do so I would add a form & listbox to choose the instance, but I cannot find ideas for the code to populate the listbox with the instance names.

Finding this information is more difficult than I expected. I see SQLDMO mentioned frequently, but many of the posts & articles are 15-20 years old, and I cannot find this DLL on my system.

I can do it easily in VB.Net as follows, but in VBA it's turning out to be an elusive answer.

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim instance As SqlDataSourceEnumerator = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance
        Dim table As System.Data.DataTable = instance.GetDataSources()
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            Console.WriteLine(row("ServerName") & "\" & row("InstanceName"))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT*** I don't think the below code will work anyway, as it seems to need `CDecl` calling convention.

---

`SqlDataSourceEnumerator` uses an internal native DLL called `sni.dll` which has no documentation.

I've made an implementation of this in VBA, but I make no claims on the reliability of this, as it's completely undocumented.

I can't even test it, as the only SQL Server I have on my network does not show up in `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` either.

You may also need to get the exact location of `sni.dll` on your machine, you may need to download the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI` NuGet package.

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Function SNIServerEnumOpen Lib "sni.dll" (ByRef handle As LongPtr, ByVal dummy As Long) As LongPtr
Declare PtrSafe Sub SNIServerEnumClose Lib "sni.dll" (ByRef handle As LongPtr)
Declare PtrSafe Function SNIServerEnumRead Lib "sni.dll" (ByVal handle As LongPtr, ByVal buffer As String, ByVal bufferSize As Long, ByRef more As Long) As LongPtr

Function EnumDataSources() As String()
    On Error GoTo finally
    Dim buffer, strbldr As String
    Dim bufferSize, readLength As Long
    Dim handle As LongPtr
    Dim more As Long
    buffer = Space(1024)

    SNIServerEnumOpen(handle, 0)
    If handle = 0 Then GoTo finally
    Do While more <> 0
        readLength = SNIServerEnumRead(handle, buffer, 1024, more)
        If readLength > bufferSize Then
            Exit Do
        ElseIf 0 < readLength Then
            strbldr = strbldr & Mid(buffer, 0, readLength)
        End If
    Loop
finally:
    If handle <> 0 Then SNIServerEnumClose (handle)

    EnumDataSources = Split(strbldr, ChrW(0))
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I do not have this file anywhere in the \Windows\ path. Since I will be sharing this widget with my coworkers, I need the solution to be something standard in Windows. But I still give a +1 for your help. Thanks.

Comment: You can get it from the Nuget package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI. But this probably won't work anyway as I think it needs `CDecl`